# Cross-table multiplication

Tags: sql, database

Here I have 3 tables:

```
    Book [Id] [UnitPrice]
    BookOrder [Id] [BookId] [Quantity]
    BookInvoice [Id] [OrderId] [TotalPrice]
```

The requirement is to get the UnitPrice from Book table, then.

```
    UnitPrice * Quantity = TotalPrice
```

I am newbie to SQL and this is my code:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER TR_TotalPrice
    ON BookInvoice *--Is that correct?*
    FOR UPDATE, INSERT
    AS
    UPDATE BookInvoice SET TotalPrice = Book.Price * BookOrder.Number
    FROM Book, BookOrder
```

....

And I have no idea how to complete these code, hope guys will help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_TotalPrice ON BookInvoice
FOR UPDATE, INSERT
AS
begin
    update BookInvoice set 
        TotalPrice = B.Price * BO.Number
    from inserted as i
        inner join BookInvoice as BI on BI.Id = i.Id
        inner join BookOrder as BO on BO.Id = i.OrderId
        inner join Book as B on B.Id = BO.BookId
end
```

or you can just use view, it's more normalized, but if book `Price` will change, `TotalPrice` of all invoices with that book will change too

```
create view vw_BookInvoice
as
   select
        BI.Id,
        BI.OrderId,
        B.Price * BO.Number as TotalPrice 
   from BookInvoice as BI
        inner join BookOrder as BO on BO.Id = i.OrderId
        inner join Book as B on B.Id = BO.BookId
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, when I after I tried the code into my project, I got several error messages prompted: The multi-part identifier "..." could not be bound. I think I have made all the table name and column name to match my database table and column. Any idea?

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vw_BookInvoice, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "OrderTable.ord_Id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vw_BookInvoice, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "invo.OrderId" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vw_BookInvoice, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "Product.pdt_Id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vw_BookInvoice, Line 9

Comment: My scenario is a little bit from the question I just put. I named the Book table as "Product" table in my database. Thanks

Comment: well if you are using `OrderTable.ord_Id` then you have to have `OrderTable` table in you query or `<some table> as OrderTable`. Take a look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196308(v=SQL.80).aspx

Comment: Sorry but I still got one error, I tried to declare the alias "FROM my_db.dbo.Invoice AS I, my_db.dbo.Product AS P, my_db.dbo.OrderTable AS O". But I still got an bound error on the "multi-part identifier "p.pdt_Id""

Comment: Here is my code in the query: inner join Product AS Item ON p.pdt_Id = O.ord_ProductId

Comment: try `inner join Product AS p ON p.pdt_Id = O.ord_ProductId`

Comment: Since your trigger updates the same table on which it's been defined, it might be safer to add a condition checking which column is being updated, to prevent recursive trigger calls: `IF UPDATE(Price) OR UPDATE(Number) UPDATE BookInvoice ...`.

Answer (score 1):

you dont have to store **TotalPrice** in the **BookInvoice**  table as you can derive the value using the values from other tables..

```
select Book.Price * BookOrder.Quantity as TotalPrice 
from Book 
join BookOrder
on BookOrder.BookId=Book.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use triggers you will need to create triggers to cover all cases. For example to update the table BookInvoice in case the UnitPrice of a book changes. Or even if the Quantity changes in table BookOrder etc.

Instead of using triggers you should probable use a view that calculates instantly the value you want. Something like:

```
SELECT b.id, bo.id, bo.quantity * b.uniprice TotalPrice
FROM BOOK b, BookOrder BO, BookInvoice BI
WHERE BO.Id = BI.OrderId
AND B.Id = BO.BookId
```